# Не получается правильно собрать dll для windows из под Linux, при помощи mingw

Tags: c, dll, mingw-w64

Есть программа (IDE, в составе которого компилятор Си, Ассемблер, Линкер, Пошаговый отладчик, Симулятор периферии и т.д для процессора mc68020). Программа старая, написана под WinXP, и работает под Linux через Wine.

Симулятор периферии имеет опцию конструирования своих собственных устройств, для этого предлагается написать dll с функцией устройства, используя API симулятора. В комплекте с IDE идёт пример такого устройства, в виде исходника, и готового dll собранного из этого исходника.

Собственно проблема заключается в компиляции dll из под linux при помощи mingw-w64.
Натравливание mingw на исходник примерно с такими ключами

`i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32 -shared -m32 -o simpledev.dll Simpledev.c`

не приводит к желаемому результату. Код компилируется без ошибок, но симулятор отказывается
его переваривать и сыплет ошибками. dll, который генерируется компилятором отличается как по весу так и по содержанию (16кб и ~50кб соответственно).

Код который нужно собрать в dll

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Simpledev.h"

#define IOBASE    0x00200000  // Base address of this device ($200000)
#define IOSIZE    6           // device needs 6 bytes ($200000 - $200005)

// global variables
HWND hwMain;                  // Visual68K main window
HWND hwDevice;                // IO device window
BYTE DeviceMemory[IOSIZE];    // Device needs 6 bytes of memory (or registers)

// Callback procedure for device dialog

BOOL CALLBACK DeviceDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char txt[4];

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_PORT_A, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, 2, 0);
        SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_PORT_B, EM_SETLIMITTEXT, 2, 0);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDC_PORT_A: // Input A
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE) {
                GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_PORT_A, txt, 4);
                DeviceMemory[1] = (BYTE) strtol(txt, NULL, 16);
            }
            break;
        case IDC_PORT_B: // Input B
                    if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE) {
                GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_PORT_B, txt, 4);
                DeviceMemory[3] = (BYTE) strtol(txt, NULL, 16);
            }
            break;
        case IDC_INT5: // Interrupt 5 button
            SendMessage(hwMain, WM_USER, 5, 0); // use level 5 interrupt autovector
            break;
        case IDC_INT6: // Interrupt 6 button
            SendMessage(hwMain, WM_USER, 6, 0); // use level 6 interrupt autovector
            break;
                case IDCANCEL: // Windows menu: close
                        SendMessage(hwMain, WM_USER, 0, 0);
                        break;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// This function is called when device is opened by the visual simulator

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL APIENTRY InitDevice(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, HWND hWnd, LPDWORD lpdwBase, LPWORD lpwSize)
{
    // save handle for interrupt commands
    hwMain = hWnd;
    // report memory region to Visual Simulator
    *lpdwBase = IOBASE;
    *lpwSize = IOSIZE;
    // Create device window (modeless dialog)
    hwDevice = CreateDialog(hinstDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), hWnd, DeviceDlgProc);
    // set focus to main window
    SetFocus(hWnd);
    // return TRUE if window is created
    return hwDevice != NULL;
}

// This function is called when the 68000 reads a byte from device memory

__declspec(dllexport) BYTE APIENTRY ReadByte(DWORD dwAddress)
{
    return DeviceMemory[dwAddress - IOBASE];
}

// This function is called when the 68000 writes a byte to device memory

__declspec(dllexport) void APIENTRY WriteByte(DWORD dwAddress, BYTE cbData)
{
    char txt[4];

    // if not changed, do not update
    if (cbData == DeviceMemory[dwAddress - IOBASE]) return;
    DeviceMemory[dwAddress - IOBASE] = cbData;
    // write to address $200005
    if (dwAddress == IOBASE + 5) {
        wsprintf(txt, "%02X", cbData);
        SetDlgItemText(hwDevice, IDC_PORT_C, txt);
    }
}

// This function is called when device is closed by the visual simulator

__declspec(dllexport) void APIENTRY CloseDevice()
{
    DestroyWindow(hwDevice);
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это скомпилировать.